# AngularJS specifying multiple values for attribute of custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am creating a directive `<chart>` in AngularJS. I want to add a attributes `x-series` and `y-series` to it.

A requirement is that these attributes should take multiple parameters like `x-series="xData1 xdata2 xdata3"` and `y-series="ydata1 ydata2 ydata3"`.

How do I resolve the different values of x-series and y-series attributes? I can do it by splitting the values of `scope.xSeries` and `scope.ySeries` by space but I want to know that if Angular provides any better way to specify attribute with multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually pass an array, for instance.

```
<chart y-series="myArray"></chart>

//in controller

$scope.myArray = ['ydata1','ydata2'];

//in directive

scope:{
  'y-series': '=' // this will set up bi-directional data binding to the array
}
```

Comment: I want the series values (or the values of `myArray`) to be specified only inside the view component.Please clarify,How can I specify that using myArray or any other way

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use keys for more information

```
x-series={key1:xData1, key2:xData2, key3:xData3}
```

This way you can distinguish using `x-series.key1` and `x-series.key2`